# What is the gestation period of a Klingon?

Tags: star-trek, biology, klingon

I am aware of the gestation periods of Betazeds is 10 months and (obviously) humans, but is the time span ever addressed of Klingon gestation?  (Perhaps VOY might have a reference with B'Elana's pregnancy, but I'm looking for purely Klingon)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon#Physiology):

> Klingon pregnancies normally ran thirty weeks, but with mixed species, gestation times were shorter.

Presumably those are standard Earth weeks.

Comment: Is Memory Alpha referencing the 30w #?

Comment: @DVK Yes, the link goes to the physiology section and that's where the quote comes from. I'm pretty sure the number itself comes from ST:VOY "Lineage".

Answer (score 8):

In the Voyager episode "[Lineage](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/710.htm)", the EMH discusses Torres' pregnancy with her husband;

> **PARIS:** *When is the baby due?*
>
> **EMH:** *Normally, **Klingon pregnancies run thirty weeks**, but with mixed species it could be sooner.*

Given that the EMH contains "*the collective information of 2000 medical references*", I think we can assume he's reasonably expert on the subject.