# Did Lursa live long enough to give birth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-generations

In the season 7, episode 21 "Firstborn", Lursa revealed she was pregnant. An heirloom brought from further in the future suggests the child would be a boy.

We know that the timeline was changed. **Was she still carrying the fetus when the Enterprise-D blew up her ship in Star Trek : Generations?**

Comment: Good question. I still want to know who the lucky guy was - Lursa's pretty cute for a Klingon.

Comment: The father isn't known. Her son is named (in the games and various low-canon novels) as Ja'Rod; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ja%27rod,_son_of_Torg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- We know that the average Klingon pregnancy is [approximately 30 weeks](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52979/what-is-the-gestation-period-of-a-klingon/53032#53032)
- The events of Generations (2371) take place more than 30 weeks after the events of TNG : Firstborn (2370)
- There's no evidence that Lursa is pregnant or that the child was on board Lursa and B'etor's Bird-of-Prey

It's reasonable to assume that the birth took place exactly as before, unaffected by the altered timeline. The child's life will obviously be drastically affected by the death of his mother.